# How can I make the content of the Slider component flex or in a row layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm new to web development and currently working on a project where I have implemented a Slider component using the react-slick library. However, by default, the content within the Slider is displayed in a column layout. I would like to change this and make the content flex or arrange it in a row layout.

I have tried applying the display: flex property to the elements within the Slider, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.